# Font becomes bold after use of \citep or \citet

Tags: biblatex

After the use of `\citep`, `\citet` (`biblatex` with `natbib=true`) or `\autoref` commands, all text until the end of the page becomes bold/thick. The problem is fixed in the next page and starts again when one of those command is used again.

Here's an image showing the problem:

[image]

NOTE:This is not the same problem other people have reported where text become bold after the use of graphics or figures as this also happens with citations which is not part of the graphics package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: does this happen with every citation or just with special ones?

Comment: This problem happens with every citation. Ok I found the problem :) I used Adobe Reader 9 v 9.5.1 03/07/2012! This caused the problem. The pdf is displayed fine but once you print everything goes wrong. Using another pdf viewer to print solved the problem :)